# mkdir: cannot create directory under /root : Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, mkdir

And here it is, another permission denied, sorry for that, but I cannot get it running.

Let me be a `stack` user with sudo permissions, so that I can create a folder `x` by `sudo mkdir /root/x`.
That's running fine. But I get permission denied without sudo, no matter what I try. I set `chown -R stack:stack /root`, and `chmod 777 /root`, but still cannot create a subfolder:

```
stack@2d11fb64044f:/$ whoami
stack
stack@2d11fb64044f:/$ ls -l / | grep stack
drwxrwxrwx   6 stack stack 4096 Sep 27 23:11 root
stack@2d11fb64044f:/$ ls /root
local.conf  logs  run.sh
stack@2d11fb64044f:/$ mkdir /root/x
mkdir: cannot create directory '/root/x': Permission denied
```

How to set `/root` folder permissions for `stack` user to be able to create a new subfolder in `/root`? It's Ubuntu 14.04 docker image.

**Edit**: Replicate with docker:

```
 x:\>docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
 root@c4d9e561f4e8:/# adduser stack
 Adding user `stack' ...
 Adding new group `stack' (1000) ...
 Adding new user `stack' (1000) with group `stack' ...
 Creating home directory `/home/stack' ...
 Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
 Enter new UNIX password:
 Retype new UNIX password:
 passwd: password updated successfully
 Changing the user information for stack
 Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []:
    Room Number []:
    Work Phone []:
    Home Phone []:
    Other []:
 Is the information correct? [Y/n] y
 root@c4d9e561f4e8:/# chown stack /root
 root@c4d9e561f4e8:/# su - stack
 stack@c4d9e561f4e8:~$ mkdir /root/x
 mkdir: cannot create directory '/root/x': Permission denied
```

Comment: I wouldn't mess with the permissions of the `/root` folder, instead, I'd give the appropriate permissions to `stack`

Comment: what permissions do you have in mind?

Comment: Why exactly do you want this folder to reside in `/root` when you could put it anywhere else?

Comment: Operations in Docker containers are trivial to replicate. Execute `docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash` then `adduser stack`, `chown stack /root`, `su - stack`, `mkdir /root/x` and you created a directory. Proved. Conclusion: you are not showing the vital information in your question

Comment: I wished it was as simple as not showing an information. But replicating what you have shown here have failed for me. Please see edit

Comment: This is how a new Docker image behaves: https://imgur.com/a/r7iIF Are you running the container straight from the image or are you doing something else in between?

Comment: This is so weird. I dropped the ubuntu image, I pull it over again, and get the same permission denied (nothing done in between). It's windows 7/VirtualBox&boot2docker. Tried with my second machine, and it works as you describe. The only difference I can see is the second machine is having docker in windows 10/hyper-V. I suspect this can have something to do with this [bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5314).

Comment: @techraf: Can reproduce OP's behavior on Ubuntu14.04(Docker)@Ubuntu16.04(Host) with a fresh container/image.